# requestAnimationFrame doesn't re-trigger on key-hold but setTimeOut does

Tags: javascript, events, requestanimationframe

I got the impression that `setTimeOut` is bad and `requestAnimationFrame` is good. So I dutifully refactored:

```
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if ( key === 70 && go_up === false && gameOver === false ) {
    go_up = setInterval( up, 50 );
    }
} );
```

into

```
document.addEventListener( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if ( key === 70 && go_up === false && gameOver === false ) {
    go_up = setTimeout( () => {
        requestAnimationFrame( up );
    }, 1000 / 50 );
    }
} );
```

In the first version, keeping the key depressed keeps re-triggering the callback, as I want. The `requestTimeOut` version does not.

How can I make the `requestTimeOut`version behave like the `setTimeOut` version please?

Comment: They (setInterval, requestAnimationFrame) do different things. The first version creates many, many interval timers. The second creates many, many timeout timers. The first sets an interval every 50ms while the second sets timeouts every 20ms. There is a lot that is different between these two code snippets. It is unlikely you need the `setTimeout()` call at all. But that depends on whether your intent is throttling or not.

Comment: I see the problem with the fps vs micro-seconds. I do need fine control over the frame rate.

Comment: remove the call to `setTimeout()` and just use `requestAnimationFrame()` there. That should easily give you 60fps with this code.

Comment: I don't understand - I thought requestAnimationFrame did not allow you to specify a frame rate?

Comment: You cannot specify a framerate with timer either. They are not precise.

Comment: It's for a game. I don't need an exact frame rate, but I do need to be able to have control over the speed. setTimeOut gives me that, so it seems like a better choice, but consensus seems to suggest I should use requestAnimationFrame. Maybe I should just ignore than and do what works?

Comment: please see my answer. I think you'll find it simplifies things a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a game, it's better to keep the game loop in its own function, instead of calling (and stopping) the game loop in button handlers. In most games, the game loop always runs, because there's always something happening (enemies moving, score board updating, etc.)

That's why `requestAnimationFrame` is so great, it won't throttle your CPU if the user clicks to another tab while your game is running.

Expanding a bit on Randy's answer here:

```
 let speed = 0
 let box = document.querySelector("#box")

 function setupGame(){
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => checkInput(e))
    gameLoop()
 }

 function checkInput(e){
      if (e.key.toLowerCase() === 'f') {
           speed = 10
      }
      // more keyboard checks here
 }


 function gameLoop() {
     let rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
     box.style.transform = "translateX(" + (rect.left + speed) + "px)";
     requestAnimationFrame(()=>gameLoop())
 }

 setupGame()
```